# How to display this animated select with a v-for?

Tags: html, jquery, css, vue.js

I want to display this select, with the options coming from a v-for, but with the v-for it doesn't work. It only works with static option tags.

I've got no errors back, but the v-for doesn't display properly.

Also the arrow icon is not showing. Here's the part of the CSS in which the icon is set.

```
.sel::before {
    position: absolute;
    // content: '\f063';
    content: "\f063";
    // font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #FFF;
    right: 20px;
    top: calc(50% - 0.5em);
  }
```

How can I fix that?

This is the jQuery script in the mounted

```
mounted() {
    /* ===== Logic for creating fake Select Boxes ===== */
    $(".sel").each(function () {
      $(this).children("select").css("display", "none");

      var $current = $(this);

      $(this)
        .find("option")
        .each(function (i) {
          if (i == 0) {
            $current.prepend(
              $("<div>", {
                class: $current.attr("class").replace(/sel/g, "sel__box"),
              })
            );

            var placeholder = $(this).text();
            $current.prepend(
              $("<span>", {
                class: $current
                  .attr("class")
                  .replace(/sel/g, "sel__placeholder"),
                text: placeholder,
                "data-placeholder": placeholder,
              })
            );

            return;
          }

          $current.children("div").append(
            $("<span>", {
              class: $current
                .attr("class")
                .replace(/sel/g, "sel__box__options"),
              text: $(this).text(),
            })
          );
        });
    });

    // Toggling the `.active` state on the `.sel`.
    $(".sel").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Toggling the `.selected` state on the options.
    $(".sel__box__options").click(function () {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      var index = $(this).index();

      $(this).siblings(".sel__box__options").removeClass("selected");
      $(this).addClass("selected");

      var $currentSel = $(this).closest(".sel");
      $currentSel.children(".sel__placeholder").text(txt);
      $currentSel.children("select").prop("selectedIndex", index + 1);
    });
  },
```

This is the select in the template

```
<div class="sel sel--black-panther">
            <select name="select-profession" id="select-profession">
              <option value="" disabled>Profession</option>
              <option value="hacker">Hacker</option>
              <option value="gamer">Gamer</option>
              <option value="developer">Developer</option>
              <option value="programmer">Programmer</option>
              <option value="designer">Designer</option>
              
              <!-- Here's the v-for I want to display but it doesn't display -->

              <!-- <option
                :value="genre.slug"
                v-for="genre in genres"
                :key="genre.id"
              >
                {{ genre.name }}
              </option> -->

              <!-- /Here's the v-for I want to display but it doesn't display -->

            </select>
          </div>

          <hr class="rule" />
```

The CSS

```
.rule {
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: none;
    height: 1.5px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #c9bbae, #f0f0f0);
  }
  
  /* ===== Select Box ===== */
  .sel {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 3em 2em;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .sel::before {
    position: absolute;
    // content: '\f063';
    content: "\f063";
    // font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-family: "Font Awesome";
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #FFF;
    right: 20px;
    top: calc(50% - 0.5em);
  }
  
  .sel.active::before {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  }
  
  .sel__placeholder {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    font-size: 2.3em;
    color: #838e95;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    text-align: left;
    pointer-events: none;
    user-select: none;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
  .sel.active .sel__placeholder {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .sel__placeholder::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    // content: attr(data-placeholder);
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  .sel.active .sel__placeholder::before {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  
  .sel__box {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% + 4px);
    left: -4px;
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: black;
    width: calc(100% + 8px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .sel.active .sel__box {
    display: block;
    animation: fadeInUp 500ms;
  }
  
  .sel__box__options {
    display: list-item;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #838e95;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .sel__box__options::after {
    content: '\f00c';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: none;
  }
  
  .sel__box__options.selected::after {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  .sel__box__options:hover {
    background-color: #ebedef;
  }
  
  /* ----- Select Box Black Panther ----- */
  .sel {
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  
  .sel--black-panther {
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  /* ----- Select Box Superman ----- */
  .sel--superman {
  /*   display: none; */
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  /* ===== Keyframes ===== */
  @keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate3d(0, 20px, 0);
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: none;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Provided v-for code looks fine. Can you show us your data function? Or wherever you're getting `genres` from?

Comment: Hi Mythos, the genres array works fine, it doesn't work only inside that animated select

Comment: I think it could be a problem in the jQuery script maybe

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-merkle-0u4jg Check this out, it seems to be working fine.